# prolog delete head from a clause

Tags: list, prolog, yap

I am using yap.
Suppose I have this scenario:

p(x,y) :- q(x), f(x,y), g(x).

I need to put the body of the predicate in a list using the command *listing(p)*.

Expected output should be:
[q,f,g].

How I can do that?

Comment: Take the output of `listing` and extract the relevant information maybe?

Comment: how can do that? i'm a prolog newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

with a service predicate

```
enum_conj((A, B),X) :- !, (enum_conj(A, X) ; enum_conj(B, X)).
enum_conj(X, X).
```

we can do

```
?- clause(p(_, _), P), setof(F, J^A^(enum_conj(P, J), functor(J, F, A)), L).
L = [f,g,q],
P = (q(x),f(x,y),g(x))
```

all builtins used are ISO standard